# ¿Como recibir los datos de pulseras como Xiaomi2 o algún Android Wear?

Tags: android, android-wear

Hola estoy comenzando con el desarrollo de wereables y desconozco en su totalidad como poder enviar datos, por ejemplo cardíacos, desde una pulsera a la aplicación, sería bueno que me recomendaran algún recurso como libros, tutoriales o cursos online

Comment: Para ayudarte de mejor manera deberías indicar la marca y modelo del wearables que quieres utilizar, así como también el avance de tu investigación y realmente poder apreciar que es lo que necesitas o te hace falta

Comment: Incluso si se indicara que marca y modelo se está utilizando, esta pregunta está basada en opiniones y es demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada dispositivo tiene su API de desarrollo que puede ser utilizada por un desarrollador, por ejemplo esta es para las pulseras fitbit
https://dev.fitbit.com/ec

Aquí encuentras la documentación:
https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/

Para Nike la encuentras aquí:
https://developer.nike.com/documentation/api-docs.html

Saludos